# Can someone help me fix the what I'm missing in my Remix Contract

Tags: remix

This is the error that I'm having trouble with:

Error! Unable to generate Contract Bytecode and ABI (General Exception, unable to get compiled [bytecode])

Also says that it's looking for a Bytecode: (See below)

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

/**
 * @title Owner
 * @dev Set & change owner
 */
contract Owner {

    address private owner;

    // event for EVM logging
    event OwnerSet(address indexed oldOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    // modifier to check if caller is owner
    modifier isOwner() {
        // If the first argument of 'require' evaluates to 'false', execution terminates and all
        // changes to the state and to Ether balances are reverted.
        // This used to consume all gas in old EVM versions, but not anymore.
        // It is often a good idea to use 'require' to check if functions are called correctly.
        // As a second argument, you can also provide an explanation about what went wrong.
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Caller is not owner");
        _;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Set contract deployer as owner
     */
    constructor() {
        console.log("Owner contract deployed by:", msg.sender);
        owner = msg.sender; // 'msg.sender' is sender of current call, contract deployer for a constructor
        emit OwnerSet(address(0), owner);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Change owner
     * @param newOwner address of new owner
     */
    function changeOwner(address newOwner) public isOwner {
        emit OwnerSet(owner, newOwner);
        owner = newOwner;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Return owner address 
     * @return address of owner
     */
    function getOwner() external view returns (address) {
        return owner;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is compiled and deployed ok on my test with remix https://remix.ethereum.org/